# How do I convert this syntax error into a proper if else

Tags: python

I'm a beginner with pyhthon and i have a problem I can't solve on my own.
This is the code I wrote:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="01_Data Analysis_Materials_v02_ergänzt.xlsx")
​
volume = [1000, 200, 150, 100, 50, 30, 20, 10, 5, 2.5, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125]
​
expanse = [1.2, 0.36, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1521, 0.097344, 0.07105, 0.045008, 0.0312, 0.014884, 0.009409, 0.005625, 0.0035, 0.0025]
​
behälter = ["IPC", "Stahl-/ Kunststofffass 200L", "Stahl-/ Kunststofffass 150L", "Kunststofffass 100L", "Kunststofffass 50L", "Kunststofffass 30L", "Kanister 20L", "Kanister 10L", "Kanister 5L", "Kleinstgebinde 2,5L", "Kleinstgebinde 1L", "Kleinstgebinde 0,5L", "Kleinstgebinde 0,25L", "Kleinstgebinde 0,125L"]
​
for x in range(1,1605):
    for b in range(0,14):
        u = (int(sheet("H"+str(x)).value)+(int(sheet("J"+str(x)).value))/((int(sheet("K"+str(x)).value)*volume[b])
        if (u > 1):
            sheet["N"+str(x)] = behälter[b-1]
            continue
        else:
            sheet["N"+str(x)] = behälter[13]
                                                                          
workbook.save(filename="01_Data Analysis_Materials_v02_ergänzt.xlsx")
```

I don't understand why the ":" is a problem?
Can somebody pls help?

```
  File "<ipython-input-15-0338f8c40d7d>", line 13
    if u > 1:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've added the Python tag so the question can be seen by those who're able to answer it. Don't forget to do so next time, since this community pretty much covers all programming languages.

Comment: My guess is that you have unmatched parentheses in the line above. You should check that. (pro tip: use a text editor that highlights matching pairs of parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

You have a malformed parenthesis expression I think. `u` should be

```
u = int(sheet("H"+str(x)).value)+(int(sheet("J"+str(x)).value))/((int(sheet("K"+str(x)).value)*volume[b]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook(filename="01_Data Analysis_Materials_v02_ergänzt.xlsx")
​
volume = [1000, 200, 150, 100, 50, 30, 20, 10, 5, 2.5, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125]
​
expanse = [1.2, 0.36, 0.25, 0.25, 0.1521, 0.097344, 0.07105, 0.045008, 0.0312, 0.014884, 0.009409, 0.005625, 0.0035, 0.0025]
​
behälter = ["IPC", "Stahl-/ Kunststofffass 200L", "Stahl-/ Kunststofffass 150L", "Kunststofffass 100L", "Kunststofffass 50L", "Kunststofffass 30L", "Kanister 20L", "Kanister 10L", "Kanister 5L", "Kleinstgebinde 2,5L", "Kleinstgebinde 1L", "Kleinstgebinde 0,5L", "Kleinstgebinde 0,25L", "Kleinstgebinde 0,125L"]
​
for x in range(1,1605):
    for b in range(0,14):
        u = (int(sheet("H"+str(x)).value)+(int(sheet("J"+str(x)).value))/((int(sheet("K"+str(x)).value)*volume[b])))
        if (u > 1):
            sheet["N"+str(x)] = behälter[b-1]
            continue
        else:
            sheet["N"+str(x)] = behälter[13]
                                                                          
workbook.save(filename="01_Data Analysis_Materials_v02_ergänzt.xlsx")
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit?